# SQL query UPDATE is not working asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access-2007, oledbconnection

I have a simple asp.net website and a simple database.

The database has a table `Users` with this structure

[image]

Now I have been trying to execute this SQL command

```
UPDATE [Users] 
SET [UserName] = 'Teazst22',
    [Password] = 'Tesst',
    [Email] = 'Test@gmail.com',
    [FirstName] = 'Test12',
    [LastName] = 'Work1',
    [BirthDate] = '30/1/1920' 
WHERE [Email] = 'Test@gmail.com'
```

Command is executed from my C# code:

```
    public static void ChangeTable(string strSql, string FileName)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection c = MakeConnection(FileName);
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
        comm.CommandText = strSql;
        comm.Connection = c;
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        c.Close();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SQL COMMAND Executed");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

}

```
public static OleDbConnection MakeConnection(string dbFile)
{
    OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection();

    if (dbFile.ToLower().Contains(".accdb"))
        // MS Access >=2007
        c.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + dbFile);
    else
        // MS Access 2003
        c.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + dbFile);

    c.Open();
    return c;
```

### }

```
 private String Email = "";
private String Username = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((Session["IsAdmin"] != null && !(bool)Session["IsAdmin"]) || Session["IsAdmin"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

   String StrSql = "Select * from [Users] where Email='{0}'";
    StrSql = String.Format(StrSql, Request.QueryString.Get("Em"));
   DataTable Dt=  MyDbase.SelectFromTable(StrSql, "Db.ACCDB");
    if (Dt.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        USTXT.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();
        PTXT.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
        EmailTXT.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
        FirstNTXT.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
        LastNTXT.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString();
        BirthDTXT.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["BirthDate"].ToString();
        Email = EmailTXT.Text;
        Username = USTXT.Text;
    }

}
protected void SaveBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String StrSql = "Update [Users] Set [UserName]='{0}',[Password]='{1}',[Email]='{2}',[FirstName]='{3}',[LastName]='{4}',[BirthDate]='{5}' WHERE [Email]='{6}'";
    StrSql = String.Format(StrSql, USTXT.Text, PTXT.Text, EmailTXT.Text, FirstNTXT.Text, LastNTXT.Text, BirthDTXT.Text , Email);

    MyDbase.ChangeTable(StrSql,"Db.ACCDB");
    Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
}
```

When executing the code no errors are shown, but when I check the database, nothing has changed... quite simply, the command is not working.

PS: the database that I'm using is Microsoft Access 2007

Comment: Are you opening connection before executing  ExecuteNonQuery ?

Comment: Is there an existing row with `[Email] = 'Test@gmail.com'`? Or are you trying to add a new row?

Comment: @SurajSingh Yes i am ..

Comment: @YacoubMassad yes there is a row ...

Comment: @Mohammed I know you've posted the query your running but how are you getting that query into your code? `comm.CommandText = SqlStr;` Can you show us how you're implementing that? As reading that, to me it could be anything especially as it's in Pascal case, which would suggest to me it's not a variable.

Comment: @HugoYates I Posted It

Comment: @HugoYates mm... What do you think ?

Comment: You're just grabbing the values straight out your form and throwing them at your database. You've got a big security issue there when it comes to SQL Injection. You've got another variable(?) at the end of your string; `Email` I don't see where this is coming from and I suspect your problem is this value. Also try commenting out the update to the Email field; I know SQL won't have an issue with such a query but I don't know about Access where you're updating the field you're filtering on (a long shot in the dark but Access does have some oddities).

Comment: @HugoYates The value (Email) that i'm getting is Sent to the asp.net WebForm as parameter and that same value is used to select from the database ...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the mdb file you are observing is in "Data Directory" folder. you might be checking wrong file. Also check the property of that **mdb** file, whether its last modified time is approx to the time you performed database operation.

Comment: I tested other commands on the DataBase (Delete and Select and Insert) they are working perfectly .. i checked the Database Modified Date and it changes when executing the command  ....

Comment: Can you please write a code which creates initialize the connection ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply this  code  put inside  the `try catch` statement and  try to catch your  error .. as i seem definitely  you can find  the  problem in this way

```
try 
{
    OleDbConnection c = MakeConnection(Database name);
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
    comm.CommandText = SqlStr;
    comm.Connection = c;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    c.Close();
}
catch  (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: put inside the try catch statement into "MakeConnection" method and simply make sure connection is  open or  not

Comment: @SamalTharangaPerera The Connection is surely opened because when i run the code the modification date on the Access File changes ...

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have a db collation which is case sensitive and you are comparing uppercase letter to lowercase letter?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx

where test = Test would not gives any results if it's case sensitive

Comment: Both are the same , Exactly the same